# How i handle this file uploading error in my mac?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, error-handling

Warning: move_uploaded_file(upload/Kol auto.png): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/selfsub/one.php on line 56

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/phpa6Q0J9' to 'upload/Kol auto.png' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/selfsub/one.php on line 56
Helloabhsg1File Uploaded.

Comment: try giving file permission as 777 or 775 to that specified folder.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your upload directory "upload" was made by you and not by apache user that need to write inside it. Assign the upload directory to the apache user or set the permissions to 0777 to allow everyone to write in it.